# Vue Typescript @Component throwing compile error. with vue-class-component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-loader

I am getting a **`Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'`** error when compiling my Vue application. It's just a **Hello World!** App, utilizing Webpack4, Vue, and Typescript. I am using `vue-class-component` and `vue-property-decorator`

I have followed almost every setup I could find and still cannot resolve this. Everything compiles and works fine if I use classic Typescript with Vue, and not the class component stuff. As soon as I try and use the decorator @Component I get the error.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vue_tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Vue JS with Typescript tutorial",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --config build/webpack.config.dev.js",
    "watch": "webpack --config build/webpack.config.dev.js --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.2",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.dev.js:

```
'use strict'

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\/.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.vue']
    },
    plugins:  [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "strict": true,
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

**What am I missing? Why does the @Component decorator fail to compile?**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {

}
</script>
```

Git Repo: [github.com/devsi/vue-tutorial/](https://github.com/devsi/vue-tutorial/)

Comment: Since experimentalDecorators is there, it's reasonable to assume that tsconfig.json didn't catch up for some reason. Since your setup is unknown, it's impossible to say for sure. Try to add syntax error to tsconfig.json like missing `}` and see what happens.

Comment: I was talking about adding syntax error to **tsconfig.json**. This is the shortest way to make sure it's parsed by TS. If  tsconfig.json isn't in use, the compiler will use default TS config which may work for most things but not decorators. The most common way to make tsconfig.json ignored is to run `tsc` with args. Please, provide all relevant details for your setup, at least package.json and Webpack config. There's not enough data to solve the problem.

Comment: You are correct. the tsconfig file is not being used. I introduced a syntax error and the code still actually tries to compile and gives me the same error. Is there a quick fix for this? Typescript is not installed globally, project specific.

Comment: There's no quickfix because it's unknown what needs to be fixed, it's specific to your setup. Please, provide all relevant details for your setup, at least package.json and Webpack config. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I see no problem here, I'd expect tsconfig to be picked up automatically. Try to specify https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configfile with something like `path.join(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json')`, and again, test it against syntax error. Or try to set https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#compileroptions to a config from tsconfig.

Comment: Hmm, none of that works either. Even specifying `configfile: path.join(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json')` (and I can log it to console to prove the file path is correct) does nothing. The syntax error is still in my tsconfig, and it still doesn't even recognise it.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the repo at the bottom of the question. I'm simply trying to bootstrap a Vue application with Typescript and Webpack 4. It's proving much harder than I imagined it would.

Comment: It was private. Made public now! I was considering vue-cli but honestly I just want to understand a little more exactly what it is that compiles the vue app with typescript. I don't like using the CLI and not really knowing what's going on. I was hoping I could achieve a working build this way (I mean it worked fine before I introduced the @component)

Comment: The error says what's wrong, `File was processed with these loaders:`. ts-loader is never triggered. As long as the code is valid ES6 and doesn't use TS features, it will be compiled. The problem is in vue-loader and the way it's supposed to interact with ts-loader appendTsSuffixTo. No wonder you didn't find working examples, there were breaking changes in last vue-loader and it isn't well-documented. I don't use vue-loader outside CLI so I can't help with this part. I'd suggest to put a bounty on the question and update it with full error and real cause (ts-loader doesn't process .vue files)

Comment: Don't have time to look into it now, but I'm currently writing an article on how to properly set up Vue2.x with typescript. Will link it here when I publish it some point this week.

Comment: As mentioned: This article might help you https://medium.com/@mail_97248/vue2-typescript3-production-set-up-92622933c690

Comment: Is the `tsconfig.json` in the same (i.e. the root) directory as `package.json`? It's simplest and best use the cli to create a new project, including TypeScript. It works every time for me.

Comment: Actually, how do you run your build command? This error occurred to me when I tried (intentionally) build just single component, using `@vue/cli-service-global` with `vue build ...` command.